# Java sorting algorithm problems

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to make a programm in java with the selection sort algorithm. So i tried this to do that but the code doesn't works.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `min` should be storing an array index, not a value of the element, so that you can actually swap two array elements after the inner for loop is done

Comment: Do not delete the relevant code from your question, it invalidates answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selection sort use this method

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[index]) {
                index = j;//searching for lowest index
            }
        }
        int smallerNumber = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = smallerNumber;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem with this code is that it doesn't swap numbers. Instead, it replaces `array[i]` with the minimum number found.
 You can modify your loop like this to do the swapping.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

          int minIndex = i;
          for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {

              if (array[j] < array[minIndex]) {
                  minIndex = j;
              }

          }
          if (array[minIndex] != array[i]) {
            int wert = array[minIndex];
            array[minIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = wert;

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an ascend order just use:

Arrays.sort(array) from java.util library

But if you need to sort descending I'd suggested to reffer to:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-sorting-arrays